# What's the maximum number of browsers a Selenium Grid node can run

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

What's the maximum number of browsers a Selenium Grid node can run, and if I want to run around 200sh browsers, do you think the Selenium Grid is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fixed selenium grid limit, but you need to have in mind:

1. Only one InternetExplorer can run on a single node. This is browser limitation, though, not Selenium. I am not sure if you would be able to start more than one InternetExplorer on one machine, but even if you can, when running tests on Intrenet Explorer, the window should be in focus, otherwise tests get messed up. And you can't have more than one window in focus, so if you like to run your tests on IE, you can't have more than one browser on the machine running the Internet Explorer browser.
2. If you can run 200 browser instances on the machine without selenium, you would be probably able to run similar number of instances using selenium grid. Of course, Selenium grid itself requires some resources, but the browser itself is much more demanding, especially when you start loading pages, and doing the tests. I doubt you would be able to do that in practice.

Probably it's also worth checking out headless browsers, as they may be faster and/or lighter than real browsers.

Update: regarding SeleniumGrid node vs machine node.

- You can have more than one SeleniumGrid node(on different ports) on a single machine.
- Each SeleniumGrid node can run only one type of browser, but can have multiple instances of this browser running simultaneously.

Again note the IE consideration from above

Comment: When you say IE, you mean a browser in general not Internet Explorer right ?

Comment: No, I mean InternetExplorer. When running tests on Intrenet Explorer, the window should be in focus, otherwise tests get messed up. And you can't have more than one window in focus, so if you like to run your tests on IE, you can't have more than one browser on the node running the Internet Explorer browser. For other browsers (GoogleChrome, and FireFox for example), there is no such limitation

Comment: That make sense. However, I don't have any requirement on the browser, so it can be any, and it also can be headless which is also fine. In that case I can run multiple browser instances on a node if its other the IE?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful.

Comment: @Jeni I am curious how one would run multiple browser instances on a single node? Isn't the point of a node to be a single Selenium driver, and single browser being driven by that driver? Each node has its own port on the Grid. If you could run multiple browsers on the same node, that would mean that you can run multiple test runs on the same port, which would defeat the need for the existence of Selenium Grid in the first place. Unless I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Asyranok, strictly you are right. I should agree on that. But I believe the meaning of a node in the question is "network node". E.g. single machine, and not a node in the Selenium grid meaning. If this is not the case, my answer is incorrect

Comment: Thanks, Jeni. @AwadOdeh. Make sure you, me, and Jeni are on the same page with the terminology around "nodes". Selenium Grid calls each registered port (and associated resources) a node, which is what I am using it to mean.

Comment: The same with Safari on macOS related to point 1 of the answer.

Comment: Did a recheck. Configuring the node there is a parameter "maxInstances". So even on the same port, you can have multiple instances, but they should be all of the same Browser type. On the same machine, but different SeleniumGrid nodes (e.g. different ports) you can also have different browsers. Again the IE rule applies

Comment: @Asyranok & Jeni, I think my question was not fully clear because I was not clear about the term "node" in selenium. However, my goal is to be able to run as much browser instances as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a specific number defined as a limit. Any number limit would be arbitrary anyway. The limit would never be on Selenium Grid handling X number of nodes too many. The limit will be on resources.

If you want to run any number of concurrent Selenium test runs on multiple devices, agents, or workspaces within machines, then Selenium Grid is the way to go.

Comment: So I can have any number of browsers running on a node as long as the resources for that node can handle it?

Comment: No, a node can have one driver on it, and thus one browser being run by that driver. But Selenium Grid can have any number of nodes. So you can have 200 nodes, and that means you have 200 driver.exe's and 200 browser windows running all at once. Theoretically. But you need a ton of resources for this. If you plan on partitioning this on a single machine, that machine best be quite powerful. Even more so if this automation is not running headless.